# Is it inefficient to import a lot of Cloud Functions into a single index.js deployment?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

It seems that Google suggests that multiple cloud functions for a project be either defined in a single index.js file, or imported into the same index.js file:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/#structuring_source_code

Yes, they can be deployed separately. But is importing them into a single index file with same npm dependencies efficient, in terms of sharing all npm dependencies and javascript compiling / memory usage? Does Cloud Functions do some sort of tree shaking for that? Or would it be better if there are a lot of functions using a lot of different npm dependencies to be defined in separate npm projects?

Comment: You've tagged the question with Firebase, but you're pointing to Cloud docs.  The way that gcloud deploys functions is different than the Firebase CLI.  Which are you asking about?

Comment: I’m using firebase. I had assumed the efficacy of having a lot of functions imported into single index file would be same for both. Firebase advertises itself as just adding some tooling and management around Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploying more code than is actually required at runtime is only really going to have an impact on your code start time, as all that JavaScript will have to be parsed and validated the first time a source file is loaded.  It will also have an impact on the amount of memory is used by a server instance.  For small amounts of extra code, these might not even be measurably significant, but it's certainly not "free".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no difference between deploying in a single file or separately. All the functions run independent from each other and do not share resources, so it makes no difference in the end. It's just a matter of what would be easier to manage, just a single file or several.

Comment: Indeed, it's for an easier code management and development experience. You can also have a look to Cloud run and this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-cloud-function-what-i-use-and-why-12bb5d3798e1)